# using Ext JS with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, extjs

i want to design login page in Ext JS designer and use ruby on rails as back-end..
i have gone through basic example following link :
   http://docs.sencha.com/designer/Designer-Getting-Started.pdf
Is there any "basic" tutorial available that can help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [simple CRUD tutorial](http://blog.writelesscode.com/blog/2010/06/14/extjs-rails-crud-application-in-7-minutes/) using ExtJS and Rails 3.0. I hope this help you get started.

Comment: thanx..but that uses natzke...can u plz  suggest me any other tutorial without natzke..

Comment: What is the issue that you face? Try creating a simple Rails application with the views as JSON result..

Comment: the problem that i am facing is how gui designed in Ext JS will get displayed when i execute my rails appn in browser?? The index page of my rails appn does have any reference to xds_index.html.. I have followed link : http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Basic_Login and http://glauche.de/2008/01/03/using-extjs-in-rails-part-2/